# How to disable styling on <pre> in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pre

I am using HTML's `<pre></pre>` to render my text as is with `\n` and spaces in a block. But bootstrap's default behaviour puts a `<pre>` block in a bordered box with a grey background. I don't want that. I want it to displayed as plain text.

How to disable that styling behavior for pre?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just do this:

```css
pre {border: 0; background-color: transparent;}
```

Check this [Vanilla CSS Un-Reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/vanilla-css-un-reset/) for default values of other properties.

Comment: I had thought of this but was wondering if there is a more elegant solution like a pre class as unstyled in bootstrap. Thanks for the useful link!

Comment: @MohitC Your wish bro, you can actually use `pre.unstyled {}` and give the CSS.